# What does the different columns in IIS log mean?

Tags: iis

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the different columns in the IIS log means. Especially the values in the time and time-taken

```
| date       | time     | s-port | sc-status | sc-win32-status | time-taken |
|------------|----------|--------|-----------|-----------------|------------|
| 15.03.2018 | 08:59:59 | 80     | 200       | 0               | 15         |
| 15.03.2018 | 08:59:59 | 80     | 200       | 0               | 0          |
| 15.03.2018 | 09:00:10 | 80     | 200       | 0               | 9921       |
| 15.03.2018 | 09:00:14 | 80     | 200       | 0               | 13687      |
| 15.03.2018 | 09:00:15 | 80     | 200       | 0               | 15000      |
| 15.03.2018 | 09:00:47 | 80     | 200       | 64              | 47000      |
```

It seems that the time-column actually says when the request was FINISHED, and the time-taken how long it took. So, to get an exactly measurment for when the request arrived, we have to take time - time-taken = request arrived. Is that correct?

Comment: Why the downvotes? What can I edit to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time-taken` field shows the length of the time that it took for the request to be completely processed by HTTP.sys.

The `client-request` time stamp is initialized when HTTP.sys *receives the first byte* of the request (so network latency is included here). HTTP.sys is the kernel-mode component that is responsible for HTTP logging for IIS activity. The `client-request` time stamp is initialized *before* HTTP.sys begins parsing the request.

`client-request` is stopped when the last (HTTP-) response occurs.

So the answer is yes and no. Yes, it's the time when the *request* reaches HTTP.sys and no, it's not the time to measure if you want the time for IIS' reply. For example, a POST request with 2megs of payload will take a lot longer to reach your application (time-taken) than a short WebDAV keep-alive message. But both will have the same 'time' stamp. If you had subtractd one from the other, the long request would have "been there", even before it was sent.